# Where is Samba on Ubuntu Netbook Edition 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba, ubuntu-netbook-remix

For some reason Samba just stopped working on my netbook and I can't find where it is in order to restart it.

I think this happened right after some recent updates...

/etc/init.d/samba does not exist...

Has this been placed in a different location on the Netbook edition...?

How can one go about finding that out...?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/etc/init.d/smbd
```

Comment: thanks that pointed me in the right direction...
sudo service smbd restart

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure samba is still installed? Just in case, you may want to install it (`sudo apt-get install samba`) which should also update it if it isn't.

For a list, check out [this site](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec293.html).

I should also mention that in the Netbook edition, little more than the UI/UX changes. Everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: sudo apt-get install kept telling me it's already installed... and all sites had it listed as /samba and not /smbd I think that resulted in my confusion... thank you for the help though...